# Fallback font not aligned in xp

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-xp

I have a coouple of labels anchored on all sides, each in its own panel (dock style fill). The labels are all set with the following relevant properties `TextAlign = BottomLeft`, `Anchor = ..Top | Bottom | Left | Right`, `AutoSize = false` and `AutoEllipsis = true`

Now the problem: In windows xp, if my chosen font does not exist and when the label text is too long so it adds ellipsis - the text align does not seem to take (the text jumps up a few pixels)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `UseCompatibleTextRendering = true` does stop the text from un-aligning. This seem a somewhat outdated workaround however.